# How do I get rid of this invisible box?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, resize, script, javascript

When I use the "direct selection tool" (not the regular selection tool) to select the image, this box randomly shows up around it... It is making the script I wrote freak out. Basically, what I need to do is resize the image to a specific dimension by inches (constrained as well), but this random box around it is not helping....

For some images, I can ungroup and group again, then run my script and it will work, but overall I need something that will work for every file. I need to be able to write this in a script, so please let me know how to do this manually... without creating a whole new file. I left the "layers" box open, so you can see how the image is (terribly) organized. The problem is EVERY image is going to be different...so I need to figure out a way to just nuke that box. I've tried deleting certain objects, I just don't understand what it is.[image]

[image]

Comment: Flatten Transparency.

Comment: i tried that as well. no luck.

Comment: Well with raster images, there's *always* a bounding box for them which really can't be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Your dancer image seems to be a JPG imported in Illustrator. Since you seem to want to use a script in Illustrator but work on raster with this software (by the way, Photoshop is easier for this), here's what you can do:

**Why not simply [crop it in Photoshop](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/adjusting-crop-rotation-canvas.html) and place it again in Illustrator.** This way you will still have that box but it will be the size of your artboard or at least smaller.

Additionally, you can also make that background transparent in Photoshop using a [layer mask](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/masking-layers.html), applying it and then importing again that image in Illustrator. Don't import as a JPG though, there's no transparency with that file format.

You will always have that bounding box when you import a JPG or any raster in Illustrator, and even with a clipping mask it will be there (plus the clipping mask box). So maybe it's easier to simply get rid of the extra white parts of your JPG.

Answer (score 0):

It's a clipping mask. You'll have to see if you can remove the clipping mask or find a way around it.

Comment: Try selecting the clipping mask (the invisible box) with the direct selection tool and deleting it.

Comment: i tried that all of this already, no luck =(

Comment: You may have to release it and find another way of doing whatever it is the mask is doing

Comment: It's not a mask.. it's a placed *raster image*.

Comment: I have tried to ungroup and group the parts of the layers ... for the sun, it works fine when i'm resizing, but for the dancer, it just doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a good way to do this through the GUI, but you can open the SVG files in a text editor and just delete the `<defs>` sections.